# Python doesn't log into Robot framework log.html

Tags: python, robotframework

Trying to log from my test script into the log.html of robot framework. I simply cannot make it work...

I have read the docs ... http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#logging-information

But still nothing inside the log.html besides the test reports. What am I missing?

I have tried the following:

```
print "output: " + "something"
logger.console("something")
logging.info("something")
sys.__stdout__.write('Got arg %s\n' % "something")
print "something"
logger.info("output: " + "something")
```

The test is run like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   Process


*** Test Cases ***
First test
    ${result} =     Run Process     python    createCommunityTest/createCommunityTest.py
    Should Be Equal As Integers     ${result.rc}    0
```

Comment: Is `createCommunityTest` supposed to be a library with robot keywords, or is it a script?

Comment: It's a python script.

Comment: When you run a Python script as a shell `Process` that makes RF captures all outputs.  But if you call your Python script as an RF `Library` then you have more control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get the process'es output in the log just like that; the `Run Process` returns a [result object](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object), and one of its attributes is `stdout`.
So to see it (in the logs), add this

```
Log     ${result.stdout}
```

There's also an attribute for the `stderr` output.

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't log when tests are failing

Comment: If it fails before getting to the `Log` statement, it's natural - it won't be executed; if that's not the case, please share your code.